# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error sending a jQuery Post to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I read a lot for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error, but I don't understand what I have to fix :(
That's the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://54.149.190.45:8000/image/upload/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'base64': 'abc'},
    success: function () {
        showResponse("Add successfully");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error(textStatus);
    }
});
```

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://54.149.190.45:8000/image/upload/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500

Comment: Do you control over your endpoint?if so what is your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your web-browser will refuse to do ajax calls on other domains, if the requested domain doesn't confirm that you are allowed to (by putting the caller domain in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header). This is a security measure.

You have to configure the server http://54.149.190.45:8000 to allow the domain 'http://localhost:8080' to use it, by setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If you don't own http://54.149.190.45:8000, you won't be able to do the ajax call.